# What can "a TXT-lockable BAR is above 4GB" mean?

Tags: linux-kernel, intel, tpm, trusted-computing

I'm trying to launch a flicker session (http://flickertcb.sourceforge.net/) that uses the GETSEC[SENTER] instruction on Intel machines in order to launch a "Dynamic Root of Trust" environment.

The error I'm getting ("a TXT-lockable BAR is above 4GB") whenever the GETSEC[SENTER] instruction is executed is retrieved with the help of tboot (http://sourceforge.net/projects/tboot/) and is decoded from the documentation of the SINIT AC module provided by Intel (http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-trusted-execution-technology).

My environment:

```
HP Compaq dc7800p Convertible MiniTower
CPU: E6750
OS: Ubuntu 12.04
Kernel: 3.2.0-60-generic (PAE and HIGHMEM disabled)
SINIT AC module: Q35-SINIT_51.bin
```

**THE QUESTION:** So BAR in this case stands for Base Address Register, but how do I find out what register is the problem and how do I fix it?

Here is the complete output of a normal boot (line 1) + flicker session (line 1069) + tboot (for error code, line 1911): http://paste.ubuntu.com/7130591/